# How to get Handler from User Profile Link in Facebook Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook

If User's Facebook account is private then we cannot get directly Handler from User profile link otherwise we can get Handler from User profile link.

Is their any api to get handler without access token?

Eg. I have one FB User profile Link from which I want to extract Handler how can i?

FB User profile link : https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001228872140&mibextid=ZbWKwL

Comment: What do you mean by "handler"?

Comment: Handler means User name

Comment: That is not available any more via API, has not been since a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Use with ID

[http://graph.facebook.com/"](http://graph.facebook.com/%22) + facebookId + "/picture?type=square For instance: http://graph.facebook.com/67563683055/picture?type=square

Comment: I need Username(Handler) from Facebook  User Profile link